# Include tabs when setRoot

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I want to setRoot to `OtherPage` and include `tabs` with it. A sample code like:

`this.navCtrl.getRootNav(TabsPage).setRoot(OtherPage)`

First get the `TabsPage` then tell the `TabsPage` to navigate to `OtherPage`. Is it possible?

Comment: please add more information

Comment: Is `OtherPage` part of `TabsPage`?

Comment: Yes it is a part of `TabsPage`

Comment: What more information you want @Aravind?

Comment: @user3449848 please take a look at the post referenced as duplicated. If it's not what you want to achieve, let me know and I'll remove the duplicate flag.